# Generate COD file for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am building a mobile application for Blackberry and am using Flash builder 4.5.

Flash Builder 4.5 does not generate a **cod** file, it generates a **bar** file for Playbook.

I have just exported my Flex application i.e an HTML file with embedded **swf**.

I used Webworks2.0 to generate a **cod** file but it is not picking up the **swf** file embedded in the **html**.

Is there any other way how I could generate a **cod** file that is a Flex application that runs on Blackberry mobiles?

Answer (score 2):

.cod files are a special version of .jar format and are compiled from Java sources [using JDE](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp) or Eclipse.

You can't generate .cod using Flash or Flex IDEs.

Also BB phones 4.x - 7.x do not support .swf in any form (neither as program, nor the browser).